# How to include a for and multidimensional array in the body of php mailer?

Tags: phpmailer

I am using PHP Mailer.

I want to add dynamic content in php to the body but I am not being able to do it.

If I add this on the php mailer body, it works.

```
$mail->Body="<h3>Dados do 1º Titular</h3><ul><li><b>Nome: </b>".$titular1_name."</li><li><b>Idade: </b>".$titular1_idade."</li><li><b>Estado Civil</b>".$titular1_estado_civil."</li><li><b>Dependentes</b>".$titular1_dependentes."</li><li><b>Rendimento</b>".$titular1_rendimento."</li><li><b>Penhora</b>".$titular1_penhora."</li></ul><h3>Dados do 2º titular</h3><ul><li><b>Nome: </b>".$titular2_name."</li><li><b>Idade: </b>".$titular2_idade."</li><li><b>Estado Civil</b>".$titular2_estado_civil."</li><li><b>Dependentes</b>".$titular2_dependentes."</li><li><b>Rendimento</b>".$titular2_rendimento."</li><li><b>Penhora</b>".$titular2_penhora."</li></ul><h3>Dados de Contacto</h3><ul><li><b>Email: </b>".$titular_email."</li><li><b>Telefone</b>".$titular_phone."</li><li><b>Localidade</b>".$titular_local."</li></ul>";
```

But I need to add this result:

```
for ($y = 0; $y <= $numberOfRows; $y++){
          for ($x = 0; $x < $maxData; $x++) {
              array_push($row, $credito, 
                   $capital_divida, $prestacao,
                  $bank, $garantias, $situacao);
                echo $row[$x]."<br>";
            }
            array_push($fullData, $row);
          }
```

This is my relevant code for this issue:

```
$row = array();
$fullData = array();
$maxData = 6;
$numberOfRows = htmlspecialchars(["numberOfRowsHTML"]);
    $titular_email = htmlspecialchars($_POST["titular-email"]);
    $titular_phone = htmlspecialchars($_POST["titular-phone"]);
    $titular_local = htmlspecialchars($_POST["titular-local"]);
    $titular_message = htmlspecialchars($_POST["titular-message"]);
    $numberOfRows = htmlspecialchars(["numberOfRowsHTML"]);
    $credito = htmlspecialchars(["credito"]);
    $capital_divida = htmlspecialchars(["capital_div"]);
    $prestacao = htmlspecialchars(["prestacao"]);
    $bank = htmlspecialchars(["bank"]);
    $garantias = htmlspecialchars(["garantias"]);
    $situacao = htmlspecialchars(["situacao"]);
```

Thank you in advance for all the help

Answer (score 0):

This code doesn't make any sense:

```
$numberOfRows = htmlspecialchars(["numberOfRowsHTML"]);
```

It looks like you're missing the name of an array you want to get this value from, for example:

```
$numberOfRows = htmlspecialchars($_POST["numberOfRowsHTML"]);
```

Your loop that assembles the array doesn't appear to do anything useful at all - you're getting values from the submission, then assembling an array which you don't use. It would be helpful if you could clarify what it is you're trying to do.